# How to create an unbounded set of differently named methods matching some patterns which can be called up on demand in C++?

Tags: c++

Currently I'm transferring from python to C++, I want to create an unbounded set of functions with which I could call on demand:

```
namespace funcs1 {
    int get_1() {return 1;}
    int get_2() {return 2;}
    //...
}

//could also be

class funcs2 {
    static int get_1() {return 1;}
    static int get_2() {return 2;}
    //...
}

int main() {
   funcs1::get_123456789(); //return 123456789
   funcs2::get_123456789(); //return 123456789
   return 0;
}
```

Since `x` in `get_x()` could be arbitraily large, I can't just create unbounded number of functions. In python, things can be done by:

```py
class FuncsMeta(type):

    def __getattr__(_, key):
        def f():
            return int(key.split('_')[1])
        return f
    
class Funcs(metaclass=FuncsMeta):
    pass
    

assert funcs.get_123456789() == 123456789
```

I'm wondering how to do this in C++. :)

Comment: You can't. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @yurikilochek I want to provide a group of functions, e.x. get_x(), for users to call. I might extract x from the function name latter, do some computation, then return some values. I might call it "pass argument by function name", instead by value or by reference.

Comment: You might wane use templates then.  ` template<int i> int get() { return i;}`
would then be later used like this 
` assert(get<123456789>() == 123456789)`
templates are the flexible way to provide generic sets of things in c++.

Comment: @Mellester Good to know the C++'s way. :)  But still wait for the exact `get_x()` call answer until someone tells me it's impossible in C++

Comment: What's the difference to `int get(int i) {return i;}`? In Python you're passing the parameter `key` to a function `__getattr__` and the result is an integer. Why does it have to be different functions and not one function with a parameter?

Comment: @ThomasSablik  In this case, I'm facing some unit-test suite that requires that. The idea is: x might be 20 different values, where I could find some pattern, and I don't want to create 20 different functions correspondingly. A concrete example is: a unit-test suite requires `get_1() == 2; get_2() == 4; ....; get_20() == 40`; could you write only one function instead of 20 functions?

Comment: How would you solve this problem in Python? What is the pattern? What is the result of `get_1234876()`? To make it clear. That's not possible in C++. If you need 20 different functions you have to write 20 different functions.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Well, the result I expect for `get_1234876()` will be `2 * 1234876`, where `2 *` is the pattern. In python, I can "create" this function at run time by metaclass.

Comment: In C++ you can write a function with `int get(int i) {return 2*i;}` or a function template with `template<int i> int get() {return 2*i}`. I think that's the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can write just one function, which takes an argument and computes the result:

```
static int getX(int input){
    return input;
}
```

In your case, you're just returning a number which seems to match the function name except for the get part. You could do something similar by just having one function and computing the answer within the body of the function, using the input argument to determine what the output result should be.

That way you will not have to generate a large number of unnecessary functions, which will simply be unmaintainable and slow to compile.

EDIT: Another example:

```
static int getX(int input){
    return input + 1;
}
```

The point is, instead of creating a number of differently named methods, you have just one method, and use pass in a "name" or argument, to compute how to get the result you want.

Comment: I hope I could do so. But I am facing a group of unit-test suites which requires a `x` when she calls `get_x()`.

Comment: The idea is: x might be 20 different values, where I could find some pattern, and I don't want to create 20 different functions correspondingly.

Comment: @xyshell well the point is if you can find a pattern, you may be able to code it, so instead of creating 20 different functions you create just one function. If you tell us what the pattern you're looking for is, it may be simple.

Comment: Well, let's do a concrete example. There's a unit-test suite which requires `get_1() == 2; get_2() == 4; ....; get_20() == 40;` could you write only one function instead of 20 functions?

Comment: @xyshell Yes, you can. Instead of writing so many different functions, write just one function and define the input and output parameters. As I do not know which testing framework you are using, I cannot comment, but the maintainable way would be to do as suggested.